# Dynamic table cell id and name is not updatable in Jquery for IE browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Once remove function is called they particular row is removed and remaining row will be updated(ids and name of that cell will be modified) with the help of below method

Chrome and firefox is working correctly when it comes to IE browser is not working(name of that cell is not modified)

please help me.........

```
function updateRowIds(row, num) {
    $(row).attr("id", "roomChoice_" + (num - 1));
    $("#roomNum_" + num).html("Room " + (num - 1));
    $("#roomNum_" + num).attr("id", "roomNum_" + (num - 1));
    $("#adults_" + num).attr({
        id: "adults_" + (num - 1),
        name: "adults_" + (num - 1)
    });
    $("#children_" + num).attr({
        onChange: "addChildAges(this," + (num - 1) + ")",
        id: "children_" + (num - 1),
        name: "children_" + (num - 1)
    });
    $("#cots_" + num).attr({
        id: "cots_" + (num - 1),
        name: "cots_" + (num - 1)
    });
    $("#deleteRoom_" + num).attr({
        id: "deleteRoom_" + (num - 1),
        onClick: "deleteRoom(" + (num - 1) + ")"
    }); //updateChildRows(num); // updating the child ids 
}
```

Comment: Please always specify the IE version(s) you've been testing with.

Comment: @donkeydown: why are you asking me? (I guess it's firefox, though)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is that the IE dev tools aren't refreshing there is a refresh button in the F12 developer tools you have to click.  It's a PITA and it collapses the DOM tree every time you use it, but your added content should show with the new values after that.

Comment: In the F12 screen all the updated rows changed the id value but name is always same its retaining the same value while its created                  look like id 3 name 7

Comment: Did you try adding a class for it to work?  Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14222123/ie8-not-refreshing-class-after-attribute-value-change

Answer (score 0):

The code looks good. There is no reason to not work. Please re-check/debug properly then hopefully you will see it works.

Or otherwise please make the problem simple with a small piece of test code in a test html file by adding jquery reference :

```
    
    function rename() {
        var num = 1;
        $('#mydiv'+ num).attr({ id: 'mydiv' + (num + 1), name: 'mydiv' + (num + 1)});
    }
```

`<div id='mydiv1' name='mydiv1'>Change my name</div>
<input type='button' value="Rename" onclick='rename()' />`